# Looking for a Visual Studio 2008 integrated diff that I can control from code

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, diff

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2008 Add-in that shows files from SharePoint. It is possible to edit file in SharePint from within Visual Studio, and I would like to give a view of the difference between the current document and the version saved  in ShaerPoint and the last published version in SharePoint.

In the past there was Super Diff, but is it still supported for Visual Studio 2008? Is it posible to control it from code?  Any other tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a free one, there is SourceGear's [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).

This very useful [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx) describes the command line values for many of the diff tools you can incorporate into Visual Studio.

This article describes [Changing the diff/merge program used by Visual Studio](http://whyiamright.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/changing-the-diffmerge-program-used-by-visual-studio/). It targets BeyondCompare (commercial) but the steps can be followed for any diff tool (using the arguments from the previous link).

There is also [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

EDIT: Just noticed you want to be able to control from code. Both of these tools have a command line interface.

Comment: The article is a nice overview of different diff tools that are stand-alone diff tools. Integration within Visual Studio is just specifying the command line, the tool itself does not run within Visual Studio (as far as I can see). I would like to have a diff tool that really integrates with VS. And I want to be able to specify the files to be compared from code...

Comment: @Serge van den Oever: as far as I'm aware, all diff tools are configured as external tools inside Visual Studio, for all source control applications. I do not know of any VS plug-ins that do not use the external tool feature for performing diffs; presumably so that you are always able to use your diff tool of choice, rather than the SCC vendors' tool.